# django thumbnail img url does not correctly rendered in html

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-media

This is HTML code piece that in my template:

```
{%load thumbnail%}
<img style="border: 1px solid #53BCB8; padding: 2px;" src="{%thumbnail 'photodir/photo.jpg' 256x256%}" />
```

And in my settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL="http://url.com/static/"
```

And this is the rendered state of HTML:

```
<img style="border: 1px solid #53BCB8; padding: 2px;" src="http://url.com/staticphotodir/photo_jpg_256x256_q85.jpg" />
```

the problem is: in the rendered html, img url does not valid. Trailing slash is missing between "static" and "photodir". How is that happenning and what is the solution? Can anybody explain?

Note: `thumbnail` template tag belongs to `sorl-thumbnail`

Comment: Please, show the code of the `thumbnail` template tag.

Comment: I'm sorry I was forget mention about `sorl`. the `thumbnail` template tag belongs to standart `sorl-thumbnail`, not mine.

Comment: In your HTMl, does adding a slash in front of photodir help at all? Example: `src="{%thumbnail '/photodir/photo... %}`

Comment: @BryceSiedschlaw Nope! It's not helped. When I added slash before photodir, thumbnail tag completely fails. No URI printed in to src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look, I created [a test project](http://cl.ly/2w1h1y0s1S23192j2A3u) for you. It works like a charm with:

```
Django==1.3.1
Pillow==1.7.6
sorl-thumbnail==11.12
```

I get /media/cache/77/c6/77c60cc55e126abe02cbe5de48693c80.png as the result. So it seems that your MEDIA_ROOT variable contains a wrong value. Please ensure it has a trailing slash.

Comment: I thought the same, although I have some doubts